# Automorphisms of surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, automorphism-groups, fibration, automorphisms

Let $X$ be a projective surface with a morphism $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$. Assume that $f^{-1}(t)\cong\mathbb{P}^1$ for any $t\neq 0$ but $f^{-1}(0)$ is the union of two $\mathbb{P}^1$'s intersecting in one point.

Does there exists a non trivial automorphism of $X$ restricting to an automorphism of the fiber $f^{-1}(t)$ for any $t\in\mathbb{P}^1$?

Answer (score 4):

I think that the answer is *yes*. Let me try to give a sketch of proof.

Your assumption implies that $X$ is the blow up at a point $p$ of a Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_m= \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(m))$.
Then the automorphisms of $X$ are precisely the automorphisms of $\mathbb F_m$ fixing the point $p$.

On the other hand, the choice of $p$ is actually irrelevant: in fact, $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb F _m)$ acts transitively both on the unique section $C_0$ such that $C_0^2=-m$ and on its complement $\mathbb F_m \setminus C_0$, and moreover $\mathbb F_m$ blown-up in a point $p \in C_0$ is isomorphic to the blow-up of $\mathbb{F}_{m-1}$ in a point *outside* the negative section.

So your question boils down whether there exist a non-trivial automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_m$ inducing the identity on the base $\mathbb{P}^1$ of the fibration $g \colon \mathbb F_m \to \mathbb P ^1$ (in fact, any such a automorphism will restrict to a non-trivial automorphism of each fibre, hence it will have lots of fixed points).

If $m=0$ then we have $\mathbb F _0 = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and then what you want is clearly true.

If $m \neq 0$, then necessarily any automorphism of $\mathbb F_m$ sends a fibre to another fibre (by the uniqueness of the fibration). Then, denoting by $\textrm{Aut}_{\mathbb P^1} (\mathbb F_m)$ the subgroup of automorphisms inducing the identity on the base, we have an exact sequence $$1 \to \textrm{Aut}_{\mathbb P^1} (\mathbb F_m) \to \textrm{Aut}(\mathbb F_m) \to \textrm{Aut} (\mathbb P^1).$$

Now for $m \geq 1$ we have $$\dim \textrm{Aut}(\mathbb F_m)=m+5, \quad \textrm{Aut} (\mathbb P^1)=3,$$
hence $\dim \textrm{Aut}_{\mathbb P^1} (\mathbb F_m) \geq m+2$, that is $\textrm{Aut}_{\mathbb P^1}(\mathbb F_m)$ is non-trivial and we are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Just two questions. How can  I get the formula for the dimension of $Aut(\mathbb{F}_m)$? What if I have two special fibers instead of just one?

Comment: The computation of $\dim \textrm{Aut}(\mathbb F_m)$, or equivalently of $\dim H^0(T_{\mathbb F_m})$, can be found for instance in Catanese's paper *Moduli of Algebraic Surfaces*, in Theory of Moduli, Lecture Notes in Mathematics Volume **1337** (1988)
http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0082805

Comment: Concerning your second question, I do not know right now. It boils down to understand whether, given any two points in different fibres of $\mathbb{F}_m$,  one can find an automorphism of $\mathbb F_m$ acting trivially on the base and fixing both. This should be non too difficult to understand, with some little work.